# Update multiple rows for 2 columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-update

Follow up to [Update multiple rows in 1 column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346755/update-multiple-rows-in-1-column-in-mysql).

What is the most efficient query for updating multiple rows in 2 columns?

```
UPDATE example_table SET variable1 = 12 WHERE id=1;
UPDATE example_table SET variable2 = 'blue' WHERE id=1;

UPDATE example_table SET variable1 = 42 WHERE id=2;
UPDATE example_table SET variable2 = 'red' WHERE id=2;

UPDATE example_table SET variable1 = 32 WHERE id=3;
UPDATE example_table SET variable2 = 'yellow' WHERE id=3;
```

Using `case` seems to be the most efficient, but how would I do it with multiple values being set at one time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a table named `categories`   and say two columns  are `display_order` and `title` Here is what  you will do :

```
UPDATE categories
SET display_order = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 32
    WHEN 2 THEN 33
    WHEN 3 THEN 34
END,
title = CASE id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'New Title 2'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'New Title 3'
END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think again CASE is the solution. The idea is to use separate CASE statements for each variable. Something like:

```
UPDATE `example_table`
SET `variable1` = (CASE
    WHEN `id` = 1 THEN 12
    WHEN `id` = 2 THEN 42
    WHEN `id` = 3 THEN 32
    END),
`variable2` = (CASE
    WHEN `id` = 1 THEN 'blue'
    WHEN `id` = 2 THEN 'red'
    WHEN `id` = 3 THEN 'yellow'
    END);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Some not need to put the this Sign on id ' ' eg: 'id' you can leave it blank...like

```
UPDATE example_table
SET variable1 = (CASE
    WHEN id = 1 THEN 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be what you want to do :

```
UPDATE example_table SET variable1 = 42,variable2 = 'red' WHERE id=2;
```

Comment: Thanks Aleroot, but your answer doesn't deal with updating multiple rows, just multiple columns.