# SQL | Update multiple rows with one query

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a method, where about 20 rows must changed. Im passing per ajax a string like "14-33-61-10 ..." for saving the order of some rows.
Here is my actual (working) code:

```
$explode = explode('--',$_POST['data']); // -> array('0'=>'8', '1'=>'4', '2'=> ... )
$i = 1;
foreach( $explode as $task ) {
    if( !is_int($task) ) continue;
    $exec = $project->exec("UPDATE tasks SET pos=$i WHERE rowid=". $task );
    $i++;
}
```

My problem is, that it takes about 1 second. 
My question: Is there a way to edit multiple rows with just one query?

Comment: check this out `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346755/update-multiple-rows-in-1-column-in-mysql`

Answer (score 3):

Sure, send a SQL string like:

```
update  tasks 
set     pos =
        case rowid
        when 13 then 1
        when 33 then 2
        when 61 then 3
        when 10 then 4
        end
where   rowid in (13,33,61,10)
```

The translation from `13-33-61-10` to `(13,33,61,10)`  is best done in PHP.

Comment: @mr_app base on code "set_pos=$i" is already incremental.. try putting your update statement after "i++"

Comment: Good point, SQL snippet updated.  You can also send multiple update statements in one go `update ...; update ...; update ...;`

Comment: Thank you. I tried both "update...,update..." and your solution. Your one one is 3 times faster.

Comment: Awesome, I never knew you could do an update in a single statement. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

If the range is short then we can use the ID IN (ids) argument.

```
UPDATE `profile` SET `app_status`=3  WHERE `id` IN (3,37,95,136,1087,1795,1817)
```

If it's long and we know that range, let's use the BETWEEN value AND value argument.

```
UPDATE `profile` SET `app_status`=3  WHERE `id` BETWEEN 3904 AND 3918
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$explode = explode('--',$_POST['data']); // -> array('0'=>'8', '1'=>'4', ... )
$i = 1;
$sql = "";
foreach($explode as $task)
{
    if(!is_int($task)) continue;
    $sql .= "UPDATE tasks SET pos=$i WHERE rowid=$task;";
    $i++;
}
$project->exec($sql);
```